# Varchar index performing faster than integer

Tags: postgresql, indexing, timescaledb

Previously, we were using a long string for the primary ID of a table. In an effort to optimize, I swapped this to a autoincrementing int8. It seems like for some reason, despite the indexes, filter is being used.

Previous ID: 0Yac17fe1a5e5ed0c9ca9a559edfef0e68b12033aa

New ID: 1

There are a few million rows.

Table def:

```
CREATE TABLE public.trades(
    "timestamp" timestamptz NOT NULL,
    old_id varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    new_id int8 NULL
);
CREATE INDEX ON public.trades(new_id, "timestamp");
CREATE INDEX ON public.trades(old_id, "timestamp");
```

explain analyze with new

```
Result  (cost=7.55..7.56 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=8.925..9.377 rows=1 loops=1)
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Limit  (cost=0.29..1.51 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=2.456..2.585 rows=0 loops=1)
          ->  Custom Scan (ChunkAppend) on trades  (cost=0.29..2.73 rows=2 width=16) (actual time=2.455..2.583 rows=0 loops=1)
                Order: trades."timestamp"
                ->  Merge Append  (cost=0.29..2.73 rows=2 width=16) (actual time=0.037..0.039 rows=0 loops=1)
                      Sort Key: _hyper_372_22771_chunk."timestamp"
                      ->  Index Scan using _hyper_372_22771_chunk_trades_timestamp_idx1 on _hyper_372_22771_chunk  (cost=0.14..1.44 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.027..0.027 rows=0 loops=1)
                            Index Cond: ("timestamp" >= date_trunc('hour'::text, now()))
                            Filter: (new_id= 1110446)
                      ->  Index Scan using _hyper_372_22797_chunk_trades_timestamp_idx1 on _hyper_372_22797_chunk  (cost=0.14..1.26 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.009..0.010 rows=0 loops=1)
                            Index Cond: ("timestamp" >= date_trunc('hour'::text, now()))
                            Filter: (new_id= 1110446)
                ->  Merge Append  (cost=0.75..6.75 rows=4 width=16) (actual time=0.040..0.043 rows=0 loops=1)
                      Sort Key: _hyper_372_22772_chunk."timestamp"
                      ->  Index Scan using _hyper_372_22772_chunk_trades_timestamp_idx1 on _hyper_372_22772_chunk  (cost=0.28..2.30 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=0 loops=1)
                            Index Cond: ("timestamp" >= date_trunc('hour'::text, now()))
                            Filter: (new_id= 1110446)
```

explain analyze with old:

```
Limit  (cost=0.14..1.44 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.152..0.153 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Custom Scan (ChunkAppend) on trades  (cost=0.14..1.44 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.151..0.153 rows=1 loops=1)
        Order: trades."timestamp"
        Chunks excluded during startup: 44
        ->  Index Scan using _hyper_372_20603_chunk_trades_old_id_idx on _hyper_372_20603_chunk  (cost=0.43..10.38 rows=8 width=16) (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=0 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (((old_id)::text = '0Yac17fe1a5e5ed0c9ca9a559edfef0e68b12033aa'::text) AND ("timestamp" >= date_trunc('year'::text, now())))
        ->  Index Scan using _hyper_372_20852_chunk_trades_old_id_idx on _hyper_372_20852_chunk  (cost=0.43..16.06 rows=13 width=16) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=0 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (((old_id)::text = '0Yac17fe1a5e5ed0c9ca9a559edfef0e68b12033aa'::text) AND ("timestamp" >= date_trunc('year'::text, now())))
        ->  Index Scan using _hyper_372_20894_chunk_trades_old_id_idx on _hyper_372_20894_chunk  (cost=0.43..13.82 rows=11 width=16) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=0 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (((old_id)::text = '0Yac17fe1a5e5ed0c9ca9a559edfef0e68b12033aa'::text) AND ("timestamp" >= date_trunc('year'::text, now())))
        ->  Index Scan using _hyper_372_21161_chunk_trades_old_id_idx on _hyper_372_21161_chunk  (cost=0.43..14.91 rows=12 width=16) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=0 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (((old_id)::text = '0Yac17fe1a5e5ed0c9ca9a559edfef0e68b12033aa'::text) AND ("timestamp" >= date_trunc('year'::text, now())))
        ->  Index Scan using _hyper_372_21183_chunk_trades_old_id_idx on _hyper_372_21183_chunk  (cost=0.43..11.61 rows=9 width=16) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=0 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (((old_id)::text = '0Yac17fe1a5e5ed0c9ca9a559edfef0e68b12033aa'::text) AND ("timestamp" >= date_trunc('year'::text, now())))
        ->  Index Scan using _hyper_372_21210_chunk_trades_old_id_idx on _hyper_372_21210_chunk  (cost=0.43..14.93 rows=12 width=16) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=0 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (((old_id)::text = '0Yac17fe1a5e5ed0c9ca9a559edfef0e68b12033aa'::text) AND ("timestamp" >= date_trunc('year'::text, now())))
        ->  Index Scan using _hyper_372_21253_chunk_trades_old_id_idx on _hyper_372_21253_chunk  (cost=0.43..13.85 rows=11 width=16) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=0 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (((old_id)::text = '0Yac17fe1a5e5ed0c9ca9a559edfef0e68b12033aa'::text) AND ("timestamp" >= date_trunc('year'::text, now())))
        ->  Index Scan using _hyper_372_21273_chunk_trades_old_id_idx on _hyper_372_21273_chunk  (cost=0.43..13.66 rows=11 width=16) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=0 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (((old_id)::text = '0Yac17fe1a5e5ed0c9ca9a559edfef0e68b12033aa'::text) AND ("timestamp" >= date_trunc('year'::text, now())))
        ->  Index Scan using _hyper_372_21347_chunk_trades_old_id_idx on _hyper_372_21347_chunk  (cost=0.43..10.38 rows=8 width=16) (actual time=0.012..0.013 rows=0 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (((old_id)::text = '0Yac17fe1a5e5ed0c9ca9a559edfef0e68b12033aa'::text) AND ("timestamp" >= date_trunc('year'::text, now())))
        ->  Index Scan using _hyper_372_21361_chunk_trades_old_id_idx on _hyper_372_21361_chunk  (cost=0.43..9.18 rows=7 width=16) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=0 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (((old_id)::text = '0Yac17fe1a5e5ed0c9ca9a559edfef0e68b12033aa'::text) AND ("timestamp" >= date_trunc('year'::text, now())))
        ->  Index Scan using _hyper_372_21400_chunk_trades_old_id_idx on _hyper_372_21400_chunk  (cost=0.43..64.65 rows=58 width=16) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=1 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (((old_id)::text = '0Yac17fe1a5e5ed0c9ca9a559edfef0e68b12033aa'::text) AND ("timestamp" >= date_trunc('year'::text, now())))
        ->  Index Scan using _hyper_372_21441_chunk_trades_old_id_idx on _hyper_372_21441_chunk  (cost=0.43..7.04 rows=5 width=16) (never executed)
              Index Cond: (((old_id)::text = '0Yac17fe1a5e5ed0c9ca9a559edfef0e68b12033aa'::text) AND ("timestamp" >= date_trunc('year'::text, now())))
        ->  Index Scan using _hyper_372_22608_chunk_trades_old_id_idx on _hyper_372_22608_chunk  (cost=0.43..44.43 rows=39 width=16) (never executed)
              Index Cond: (((old_id)::text = '0Yac17fe1a5e5ed0c9ca9a559edfef0e68b12033aa'::text) AND ("timestamp" >= date_trunc('year'::text, now())))
        ->  Index Scan using _hyper_372_22703_chunk_trades_old_id_idx on _hyper_372_22703_chunk  (cost=0.43..24.82 rows=21 width=16) (never executed)
              Index Cond: (((old_id)::text = '0Yac17fe1a5e5ed0c9ca9a559edfef0e68b12033aa'::text) AND ("timestamp" >= date_trunc('year'::text, now())))
        ->  Index Scan using _hyper_372_22934_chunk_trades_old_id_idx on _hyper_372_22934_chunk  (cost=0.43..10.48 rows=8 width=16) (never executed)
              Index Cond: (((old_id)::text = '0Yac17fe1a5e5ed0c9ca9a559edfef0e68b12033aa'::text) AND ("timestamp" >= date_trunc('year'::text, now())))
        ->  Index Scan using _hyper_372_23089_chunk_trades_old_id_idx on _hyper_372_23089_chunk  (cost=0.43..12.47 rows=10 width=16) (never executed)
              Index Cond: (((old_id)::text = '0Yac17fe1a5e5ed0c9ca9a559edfef0e68b12033aa'::text) AND ("timestamp" >= date_trunc('year'::text, now())))
        ->  Index Scan using _hyper_372_23131_chunk_trades_old_id_idx on _hyper_372_23131_chunk  (cost=0.43..8.99 rows=7 width=16) (never executed)
              Index Cond: (((old_id)::text = '0Yac17fe1a5e5ed0c9ca9a559edfef0e68b12033aa'::text) AND ("timestamp" >= date_trunc('year'::text, now())))
        ->  Index Scan using _hyper_372_23180_chunk_trades_old_id_idx on _hyper_372_23180_chunk  (cost=0.42..2.64 rows=1 width=16) (never executed)
              Index Cond: (((old_id)::text = '0Yac17fe1a5e5ed0c9ca9a559edfef0e68b12033aa'::text) AND ("timestamp" >= date_trunc('year'::text, now())))
Planning Time: 18.880 ms
Execution Time: 1.148 ms
```

It seems like it's filtering on new_id instead of using the given index, but I'm unsure why.

```
explain analyze select *
            from trades
            where new_id= 1110446
            and "timestamp" >= date_trunc('year', now()) order by timestamp asc limit 1
```

Comment: Could you show us your query?

Comment: What's the size (in KB/MB/GB) for each index?

Comment: This seems to be a question about the timescaledb extension rather than about PostgreSQL alone, so I have added that tag.

Comment: @D-Shih added queries (sorry, thought I added them already)

Comment: What is the partitioning scheme?

Comment: Those two plans are for different queries, neither one of which are the one you showed.